# Subquery returns more than 1 row when using find_in_set

Tags: php

I have a field called 'evaluator' that holds the names of those who already have been evaluated.
Now, what I want to do is hide the subjects that have already been evaluated.
This is just a snippet of the code. The code works until `counter < 5`. When I run the program with FIND_IN_SET like this, it returns the following error 'Subquery returns more than 1 row'.

```
    $id = $user['studentsID'];
    for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++){
        $subject = $subjects[$i];

        $subquery .= "code = '$subject' AND taught  = '$taught' AND counter < 5 and 
        FIND_IN_SET(evaluators, (
        SELECT student_name
        FROM evaluation_result_student
        WHERE student_id = '$id' 
        )) = 0 OR ";    
                            }
```

PS: When I evaluate, the data saved in my field 'evaluator' is (for example): `"Juan Luna---"`, and then when another person evaluates, it goes like this: `"Juan Luna---Jacob Sen---"`.

Please help!

Comment: Add LIMIT 1 to the end of your subquery.

Comment: Adding LIMIT 1 fixed the error but the subject still shows up to the evaluator even though the evaluator already evaluated the subject.